# Python TypeError: 'NoneType' object does not support item assignment

Tags: python, api, python-requests

I try to get data from Yealink Management Cloud Service via API service by the Python scripts below. But I get the error "TypeError: 'NoneType' object does not support item assignment".

How to fix this issue? I'm using Python 3.10 to run the below Scripts.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import hmac
import hashlib
import base64
import time
import uuid
import requests
from hashlib import md5
import json
from urllib3 import encode_multipart_formdata

requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings()

accesskeyId = "f8517322d648ffa7ff758ccd17"
accesskeySecret = "11e47ef340e698eec4d5ea3"
base_url = 'https://api-dm.yealink.com:8445/'


def doRequest(method, uri, query, body, isForm):
    url = base_url + uri
    if not isForm:
        headers = buildHeaders(method, uri, query, body)
        headers['Content-Type'] = "application/json;charset=UTF-8"
    else:
        headers = buildHeaders(method, uri, {}, {}) 
    print(headers)
    
    if method == 'GET' and len(query) > 0:
        parameter =getQueries(query)
        r = requests.get(url, headers = headers, params = parameter, verify=False)
        print (r.text, r.status_code)
        
    if method =='POST':
        if not isForm:
            jsonBody = json.dumps(body)
            r = requests.post(url, headers = headers, data = jsonBody, verify=False)
            print (r.text, r.status_code)
        else:
            encode_data = encode_multipart_formdata(body)
            body = encode_data[0]
            headers['Content-Type'] = encode_data[1]
            r = requests.post(url, headers = headers, data = body, verify=False)
            print (r.text, r.status_code)
            
            
def buildHeaders(method, uri, query, body):
    headers ={}
    if len(body) > 0:
        headers['Content-MD5'] = str(base64.b64encode(md5(json.dumps(body).encode("utf-8")).digest()).decode("utf-8"))
        headers['X-Ca-Key'] = str(accesskeyId)
        headers['X-Ca-Nonce'] = str(''.join(str(uuid.uuid4()).split('-')))
        headers['X-Ca-Timestamp'] = str(int(round(time.time() * 1000)))
        headers['X-Ca-Signature'] = str(base64.b64encode(hmac.new(accesskeySecret.encode("utf-8"), sign(method, uri, query, body , headers).encode("utf-8"), digestmod=hashlib.sha256).digest()).decode('utf8'))
        return headers
    
def getQueries(query):
    formattedQueryString = ""
    paramIndex = 0
    for p in query:
        formattedQueryString += str(p) +"="+ str(query[p])
        paramIndex += 1
        if paramIndex != len(query):
            formattedQueryString += "&"
    return formattedQueryString

def buildHeaderString(headers):
    header_string = ""
    for key,value in headers.items():
        if len(value) == 0:
            continue
        if len(header_string) > 0:
            header_string += "\n"
        header_string+=key
        header_string+=":"
        header_string+=value
    return header_string

def sign(method, uri, query, body , header):
    header_string = buildHeaderString(header)
    stringToSign = method + "\n"+ str(header_string) + "\n" + uri
    if len(query) > 0:
        stringToSign += ("\n" +getQueries(query))
    return str(stringToSign)


# Get data
print("GET the Details:")
doRequest('GET','api/open/v1/manager/mvc/MVCInfo/get', {"id": "805061D10004477"},{},False)
```

After I run the script, I got the error as below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\...\PythonScripts\test.py", line 105, in <module>
    doRequest('GET','api/open/v1/manager/mvc/MVCInfo/get', {"id": "803061D100004477"},{},False)

  File "C:\Users\...\PythonScripts\test.py", line 24, in doRequest
    headers['Content-Type'] = "application/json;charset=UTF-8"

TypeError: 'NoneType' object does not support item assignment
```

Example of a Successful Response should be like this

[Example of a Successful Response here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lwA7m.png)

Comment: `buildHeaders` doesn't return anything if `len(body) == 0` (so `None` is implicitly returned), and apparently `body` is empty. That's at least the case with `buildHeaders(method, uri, {}, {}) `.

Answer (score -1):

Check that you are not at any point passing 'None' to doRequest()'s body parameter. You are trying to reassign a value to an object which is 'None', and that is what is causing your problem.

Comment: This can't be the issue. `len(None)` is a different error, and that error would occur before the one they're getting. They must be passing an empty object to `buildHeaders`.

Comment: It still works when I try with POST method like this:

print("POST Retrieving the Alarm by Paging:")
doRequest('POST','api/open/v1/manager/alarm/getList',{},{"limit":1000,"skip":0},False)